# Tirar Foto pela Webcam utilizando java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aplicação-web, webcam

Pessoal alguém sabe como eu faço para capturar fotos da web cam por uma aplicação web atrves de algum plugin java script e passar isso para o servidor via POST? A e de preferencia que a foto ficasse em um tamanho e qualidade boa(hd ou full hd).

Comment: Veja este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417036/how-to-access-the-webcam-by-javascript

Comment: Este aqui é o que você procura, tirando uma foto via webcam: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/